# Subspaces of Vector Space??

Tags: vector-spaces

say i have some vector space R^3 , then is it possible to have a subspace of that vector space whose elements belong to R^2 or does that not make any sense,?? i had a question about this in a text and got really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a vector subspace that is **isomorphic** to $\mathbb{R}^2$, as a plane in the space $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the vectors on this plane have three components so are elements of  $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are of the form $(a,b)$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are of the form $(a,b,c)$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

So elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ **cannot** belong to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and so, the answer is clearly "no".

That said, there are parts of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that "look like" $\mathbb{R}^2$ : for example, the subset $P=\{(x,y,0);\,(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is said to be *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This precisely means that there exists a bijective and linear map from $P$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.